# Flutter pause a For loop

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, delay, pause

I want to write a function with a For loop to select players randomly.
My function is as follows and works perfectly:

```
void choixJoueur() {
    for(int i = 1; i<=50; i++){
        int j1=0;
        int j2=0;
        print("iteration : ${i}");
        while(j1 == j2){
          j1 = Random().nextInt(joueurs.length);
          j2 = Random().nextInt(joueurs.length);
          print(j1);
          print(j2);
        }
        setState(() {
          joueurDuel1 = joueurs[j1];
          joueurDuel2 = joueurs[j2];
        });
    }
  }
```

But I want to add a pause to allow the animation to be visible (the function is in the build method).
I transformed my function above with a Future.delayed as follow:

```
void choixJoueur() async {
    for(int i = 1; i<=50; i++){
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
        int j1=0;
        int j2=0;
        print("iteration : ${i}");
        while(j1 == j2){
          j1 = Random().nextInt(joueurs.length);
          j2 = Random().nextInt(joueurs.length);
          print(j1);
          print(j2);
        }
        setState(() {
          joueurDuel1 = joueurs[j1];
          joueurDuel2 = joueurs[j2];
        });
    }
  }
```

The result is very strange. An extract hereunder:

```
flutter: iteration : 10
flutter: 2
flutter: 2
flutter: 1
flutter: iteration : 1
flutter: 0
flutter: 1
flutter: iteration : 11
flutter: 3
flutter: 0
flutter: iteration : 2
flutter: 0
flutter: 0
flutter: 2
flutter: 3
flutter: iteration : 3
```

I tried several methods:

- sleep -> do not show the page until the end of the loop
- Timer -> same behavior as `Future.delayed`

Comment: So why don't you call the `choixJoueur()` after the delay instead of adding it inside the method itself? Do you need the delay for each iteration?

Comment: Yes, I need the delay for each iteration. Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that what you are observing are two overlapping executions of `choixJoueur` occurring.

Comment: Indeed... The function choixJoueur() is called in the build method. I think that the setStates in the function forces a new build that triggers a new call to the function. It doesn't seem to cause any problem when there is no delay but when I insert a Future.delayed the mess begins. I tried with a Timer and that gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !
I effectively have to use

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

but it must be placed in the init and not in the build. If placed in the build it creates a mess.